# Highlight text does not show highlighted text in pdf document

Tags: highlight, react-pdf

I am implementing the text highlight function when searching for a specific string, everything seems to work fine until, that is, the search is correct, the markup in the text layer is also correct, but when it comes to highlighting the text in the document this does not happen. I'm using the recipe as is, and I've also loaded the textlayer css. Any ideas to try. Thanks for the help

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using:

1) For the styles:
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css';

2) For the render:
const textRenderer = ({ str, itemIndex }) => {
    if (str.includes(searchText)) {
        return str.replace(searchText, "<mark>" + searchText + "</mark>")
    }
    else return str
};

3) For de PDF component:
<Document file={samplePDF}>
    <Page
      pageNumber={1}
      customTextRenderer={textRenderer}
    />
</Document>